# Flot won't plot() in dynamically-added element

Tags: jquery, ajax, flot, handlebars.js

I'm working on a stats dashboard, and I'd like to populate the individual chart+table panels with Ajax. Originally I had just statically defined the HTML of the empty panels, but since I started templating them with handlebars Flot just doesn't want to cooperate:

```
Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null
```

Code:

```
<style type="text/css">}
    .dashboard-chart { min-height: 150px; }
</style>
<div class="row" id="dashboard-container"></div>
<script id="dashboard-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div id="{{dashboard-id}}" class="dashboard-section col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h1 class="panel-title">{{dashboard-title}}</h3></div>
            <div class="panel-body row-fluid">
                <div id="{{dashboard-id}}-chart" class="dashboard-chart col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <table id="{{dashboard-id}}-table" class="dashboard-table table table-striped">
                        <thead>{{{dashboard-thead}}}</thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                    {{{dashboard-content}}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var baseurl = "/foo_app/"
$(function(){
    // get template
    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#dashboard-template").html());
    // define dashboards
    var dashboards = [
        {
            templateargs: {
                "dashboard-id": "servertypes",
                "dashboard-title": "Server Types",
                "dashboard-thead": "<tr><th>Type</th><th>Count</th></tr>",
                "dashboard-content": ""
            },
            ajaxurl: baseurl + "ajax/test.php?type=servertypes",
            callback: function(data) {
                console.log(chart);
                console.log(chart.width());
                console.log(chart.height());
                $.plot(chart, data, chart_options); // !! -- problem here -- !!
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                    table.append("<tr><td>"+data[i]['label']+"</td><td>"+data[i]['data']+"</td></tr>");
                }
            }
        }
    ];
    // define chart options
    var chart_options = {
        series: { pie: { show: true, innerRadius: 0.5 } },
        legend: { show: false }
    }

    for( i=0, l=dashboards.length; i<l; i++ ){
        // append dash item
        $("#dashboard-container").append(template(dashboards[i]["templateargs"]));
        // get current dash id
        var cur_id = dashboards[i]["templateargs"]["dashboard-id"];
        // get chart/table references
        var chart = $(cur_id+"-chart");
        var table = $(cur_id+"-table tbody");
        // request data
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: dashboards[i]["ajaxurl"],
            error: function() { alert('AJAX error'); },
            success: dashboards[i]["callback"]
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

The renders as below in the DOM source:

```
<div id="servertypes" class="dashboard-section col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h1 class="panel-title">Server Types</h1></div>
        <div class="panel-body row-fluid">
            <div id="servertypes-chart" class="dashboard-chart col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <table id="servertypes-table" class="dashboard-table table table-striped">
                    <thead><tr><th>Type</th><th>Count</th></tr></thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `chart` object dumps out to console as:

```
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → openstack_inventory, selector: "servertypes-chart" }
```

But the width and height are both dumped to console as `null`. I've tried specifically setting the width and height via `style` properties in the template, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your console output: `selector: "servertypes-chart"` which leads to no html element being found for your chart. That needs to be `"#servertypes-chart"` for an [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Change

```
var chart = $(cur_id+"-chart");
var table = $(cur_id+"-table tbody");
```

to

```
var chart = $("#" + cur_id+"-chart");
var table = $("#" + cur_id+"-table tbody");
```

Comment: ughhhh I am *so dumb*. `:I`